# Passing Ctrl-Y to Avaya switch with netmiko

Tags: python, automation, network-programming, avaya

I am trying to automate the retrieval of switch information (config, mac-address-table, lldp info) from an Avaya ERS 5000 using python and netmiko.

When opening an SSH session to the switch, Avaya requires that you enter Ctrl-Y to get to a text menu and then enter another key (c) to get to the CLI.

I have tried the following the code below, which yields a timeout exception. 
When I strip away the try/except, I see the following output.

As best I can tell from inserting print() statements at various places, the session is established and then times out.

Is there more info I can extract from the netmiko exception that would illuminate where this process is going wrong?

I'll admit up front that coding and I are very recent acquaintances and I may be missing the obvious.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connecting to switch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./netmiko-test4.py", line 24, in <module>
    ssh_connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**avaya5000_ers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 100, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 525, in establish_connection
    raise NetMikoTimeoutException("Timed out waiting for data")
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for data
```

<<----begin code fragment---->>

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import netmiko

# Avaya presents Enter Ctrl-Y to begin.
CTRL_Y = '\x19'

avaya5000_ers = {
    'device_type': 'avaya_ers',
    'ip':   'a.b.c.d',  #ip obscured for posting
    'username': 'user1',
    'password': 'password',
}

try:
    ssh_connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**avaya5000_ers)
    ssh_connection.write_channel(CTRL_Y)
    ssh_connection.send_command('c')
    print(ssh_connection.send_command('show clock')) #a test command  
    ssh_connection.disconnect()   
except netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException:
    print("timed out")
```

Comment: It looks like you can't establish initial connection to Avaya switch. Can you try to connect via ssh client from the same host?

Comment: SSH works from same and other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious here seems to be to give the "banner disabled" config setting on the switch - unless you have it there for legal reasons.